# How can I push a local submodule to a remote repository on Github?

Tags: git, github

I started with creating a repo on Github (https://github.com/BenEngbers/BasexCpp)

I then created a local Git repository and added 2 submodules.
This is .git/config for my master:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:BenEngbers/BasexCpp.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

And this is .gitmodules:

```
[submodule "libBasexTest"]
    path = libBasexTest
    url = git@github.com:BenEngbers/BasexCpp.git
[submodule "libBasexCpp"]
    path = libBasexCpp
    url = git@github.com:BenEngbers/BasexCpp.git
```

EDIT

I changed .gitmodules to:

```
[submodule "libBasexTest"]
    path = libBasexTest
    url = ../libBasexTest
[submodule "libBasexCpp"]
    path = libBasexCpp
    url = ../libBasexCpp
```

Now I see that libBasexCpp @ ef9a760 points to https://github.com/BenEngbers/libBasexCpp/tree/ef9a7608c089e76415a58537540c31ec1661cf0e

What should be a correct value for url?

END EDIT

I first used

```
git submodule add git@github.com:BenEngbers/BasexCpp.git libBasexTest
git submodule add git@github.com:BenEngbers/BasexCpp.git libBasexCpp
```

to add the modules to the remote repo. And ater adding content to both submodules, I used

```
git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
```

to push to the remote.

After pushing Git reports that everything is up to date but when I try to open the submodule on the remote, I get a notification of an error ("Looks like something went wrong").

All the information I found on Google tells how to import remote submodules to a local repo but I didn't find any instruction on how to first create a remote submodule and then push to the new module.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Submodules are separate repositories. They need to point to separate remote repositories.

This:

```
[submodule "libBasexTest"]
    path = libBasexTest
    url = git@github.com:BenEngbers/BasexCpp.git
[submodule "libBasexCpp"]
    path = libBasexCpp
    url = git@github.com:BenEngbers/BasexCpp.git
```

is wrong because both your local submodules point to the same remote repository `git@github.com:BenEngbers/BasexCpp.git`. Think of submodules as different separate projects, and you need on project as part of another. This submodule could be part of multiple parent projects.

I think you might have been on the right track with your edit, but the URLs you changed to do not seem to be repositories: repositories on github usually end with .git.

---

How do you solve this? You need to create a repository on github, for each submodule. When this is done, you add the submodules to your parent repo with:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:BenEngbers/libBasexTest.git libBasexTest
git submodule add git@github.com:BenEngbers/libBasexCpp.git libBasexCpp
```

Note, each directory/submodule has its own URL to its own remote repo.

When you make changes in your directory `libBasexTest` or `libBasexCpp`, you work inside the submodule, you commit and push to these remotes. Nothing to do with the parent repo `BasexCpp`, the work is separate.

In commits you make in the parent repo, you *point out which commit of the submodules must be used*. The parent repo is not aware of the content of the submodules: the only thing it knows is "in that directory, I must checkout commit [SHA-1] from the URL git@github.com/asdfasdfasdf".

Comment: It was my misunderstanding that the git push command would also push local repositorys which had already been created. This was partly caused by interpreting examples I found on internet.
When looking at .gitmodules for SWI-Prolog, is see that the URL for the first entry is "url = ../packages-chr.git" and not "url = https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-chr.git".

What is the difference between both?

Comment: @ben engbers I know that some tools (gitlab?) require relative URL paths instead of absolute, I think it has to do with authentications.